# Почему тег form в к относительному адресу добавляет "?"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, form, action

Есть форма в node.js, атрибут action="/registration". Файл registration.html существует и находится в той-же директории, что и index.html . Почему при клике на кнопку в form к адресу добавляется "?", и получается
http://localhost:3000/registration?
Что не так? И что означает знак "?"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте для подобных форм и запросов метод `POST`

Для этого добавьте атрибут `method` с соответствующим значением

Пример для формы:

```
<form method="POST">
....
</form>
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогли, объясните пожалуйста популярным языком отличия этих методов, никак не могу въехать)

Comment: Не буду цитировать, прилагаю ссылку) - http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/method

Answer (score 4):

Обычно знак "?" в URL означает что после него пойдут get-параметры.
Например,  http://localhost:3000/registration?name='John'&surname='Smith'

В вашем случае, скорее всего, форма отправляется методом GET, вот и добавляется "?"